# Регулярное выражение для гиперссылок

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, .net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочие Regexp (.NET) для гиперссылок.
Сейчас пользуюсь регекспом вида:

```
@"(?<protocol>http(s)?)://(?<server>([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*(?<basedomain>[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+))+((:)?(?<port>[0-9]+)?(/?)(?<path>(?<dir>[A-Za-z0-9\._\-/]+)(/){0,1}[A-Za-z0-9.-/_]*)){0,1}"
```

Но парсит не все ссылки, к сожалению, например, такие не принимает:

> `http://regexlib.com/%28A%28-umS_xFKaqoVVf9qVIJUf1Zy7GjFNovSUv_QSprOszdQi3qMJRTXbLp9XIzGZOdY9B8Xq3gtGPTkGYEe5C6Rg6XjA0fwU_JkMeaaE2ONmrRbxhFFfAt9Y-AEfyujh9NpzsN268y6Dh25xbgqyzTzjkY8AKB8_7uLPmDk2wgufsFSxx39e269HFBLoTs8wMhX0%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx`

Такую ссылку может распарсить другая регулярка:

```
"^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?$"
```

Но она обламывается, когда встречает текст вида:

> `''http://edition.cnn.com/\"javascript:CNN_handleOverlay('opt_out_cnn')\"/''.`

Comment: а что за записи: <protocol>, <basedomain>... ?)

Comment: Это именованные группы, можно и не именовать их, а обращаться по порядковому номеру, но мне так удобнее.

Comment: посмотрите [8 полезных регэкспов с наглядным разбором](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/regex/66931/), в комментариях оспаривают годность примеров, но всё же

Comment: Приведу цитату из комментариев "для обучения покатит, а для реального использования не очень", так и есть, я уже пробовал их. В общем, если нет хороших регулярок, пойду сам составлять тогда, авось что-нибудь полноценное создам.

Comment: Если несложно, приведите, пожалуйста, URL, для которого не работает, например, URL данного вопроса разбирается на:

    protocol => 'http'
    path => 'questions/51778/'
    server => 'hashcode.ru'
    basedomain => 'hashcode.ru'
    dir => 'questions/51778/'

`http://www.tyres.spb.ru/index.php?mid=31` =>

    protocol => 'http'
    path => 'index.php'
    server => 'www.tyres.spb.ru'
    basedomain => 'spb.ru'
    dir => 'index.php'

Comment: но ведь http://www.tyres.spb.ru/index.php?mid=31 и http://www.tyres.spb.ru/index.php разные ссылки
так же в http://homenet.beeline.ru/index.php?showforum=730 дальше index.php не видит

Comment: По регулярному выражению и не должен. А если по вашему мнению должен парсить, то куда он `query_string` должен положить?

Касаемо ссылки с regexlib.com, по вашему мнению как она должна быть правильно разобрана?

Comment: Ну, например, вот такая регулярка её разбирает 

`^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&%\$#_]*)?$`

Просто я хочу найти более-менее универсальную, чтобы большинство ссылок попадали под неё.

Comment: Так сначала составь список URL-ей которые должны попадать под рег.выражение, потом составь какие части URL-я куда должны попадать (protocol,server,port) а потом напиши свое. Там ничего сложного нету. Долго и нудно - согласен :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак вот она, рыба моей мечты!

```
(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Справляеться со многими видами html ссылок, например вот с такими:

```
http://homenet.beeline.ru/index.php?showforum=783

http://regexlib.com/%28A%28-umS_xFKaqoVVf9qVIJUf1Zy7GjFNovSUv_QSprOszdQi3qMJRTXbLp9XIzGZOdY9B8Xq3gtGPTkGYEe5C6Rg6XjA0fwU_JkMeaaE2ONmrRbxhFFfAt9Y-AEfyujh9NpzsN268y6Dh25xbgqyzTzjkY8AKB8_7uLPmDk2wgufsFSxx39e269HFBLoTs8wMhX0%29%29/DisplayPatterns.aspx

http://edition.cnn.com/\\\"javascript:CNN_handleOverlay('no_cookie_cnn')\\\"/"
```

Если обнаружите вдруг что эта регулярка с каким то текстом не справляется, напишите пожалуйста сюда, будем дальше искать или дорабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Вам [сюда](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uri) -> Разбор структуры URI

Нужно было слеши экранировать:
`^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^\?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`

Comment: Там есть регулярка `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?`, но это вроде не для .Net

Comment: Регулярки - они (за малым исключением) общие) Тут тонкостей не используется)

Comment: Не работает она в общем.

Comment: С экранированными слешами тоже обламывается на строке вида
http://edition.cnn.com/\\\"javascript:CNN_handleOverlay('no_cookie_cnn')\\\"/

Comment: Это строка не верного формата)  на ней и не должно работать<br>
Советую почитать [URL][1]->кодирование

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: это просто строка, в которой нужно найти с помощью регулярного выражения http адрес(в данном случае это адрес http://edition.cnn.com), регулярка что ниже - это делает.

Comment: Вы как-то не так делаете - всё находит)